# python Find if a JSON file object contains a specific value

Tags: python, json

I have a code that finds a fixed value，But i need a code to check if a JSON file key contains a specific value, how should i modify it，I am a newbie and I am learning it

my code

```
import json

with open ('G:\\1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    with open('G:\\1.json', encoding='utf-8') as j:
        for line in j:
            if (d := json.loads(line))['_source']['sex'] == 'female':
                print(json.dumps(d), file=out)
```

JSON file

```
{"person":{"name":"Silva","sex":"female","age":21}}
{"person":{"name":"LANA","sex":"male","age":28}}
{"person":{"name":"Oliveira","sex":"female","age":35}}
{"person":{"name":"KENN","sex":"male","age":32}}
```

I want the output，"age" contains "2"

```
{"person":{"name":"Silva","sex":"female","age":21}}
{"person":{"name":"LANA","sex":"male","age":28}}
{"person":{"name":"KENN","sex":"male","age":32}}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code? what's the output?

Comment: FYI, that file has no outer container so it's not proper JSON. JSON is also not delimited by lines, but in this particular case you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a number contains a digit, convert it to a string.

```
d = json.loads(line)
age_string = str(d['_source']['age'])
if "2" in age_string:
    print(json.dumps(d), file=out)
```